# Models column date format

Tags: date, laravel-5, model, format

I modified my models date property to can calculate birthdays, but now when the date is loaded in my form(I use Form collective) I get it like `1979-07-17 00:00:00` right output should be `1979-07-17`

```
protected $dates = ['geburtstag'];

   public function age()
    {
        return $this->geburtstag->diffInYears(Carbon::now());
    }
```

I tried to modify from model like

`protected $geburtstagFormat = 'Y-m-d';`

but did not help.

What I do wrong in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use `$model->geburtstag->format('Y-m-d')`?

You can also create a mutaror in your model like:

```
public function getGeburstagDateAttribute($value) {
    return $this->geburtstag->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

and use it like this:

```
$model->geburtstag_date // outputs geburtstag date in 'Y-m-d' format
```

To set the date format in a model, use `protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d';` inside the model.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it 
First parse the $this->geburtstag->diffInYears(Carbon::now())

```
$createdAt = Carbon::parse($this->geburtstag->diffInYears(Carbon::now()));
```

Then you can use

```
$suborder['payment_date'] = $createdAt->format('M d Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to store the time of birth you should change the data type in your database to `date` instead of from `timestamp` or `datetime`. This will solve the problem automatically since when you call the attribute on your view, this extract exactly how it's shown on database. Otherwise, if you want to keep the database unchanged you have to define a mutator in your model, like this:

```
    public function getGeburstag($value){
        return Carbon::parse($value)->toDateString();
    }
```

This will replace the original value of `geburtag` attribute to its values in `Y-m-d` format.

Comment: I have the field as date, and the suggested mutator does not work in my case